# Where do I export gnome-keyring-daemon's ssh agent socket so that it is available at launch of WM?

Tags: environment-variables, i3, ssh-agent, gnome-keyring

I use gnome-keyring to manage my ssh keys. In order for that to work, I must set `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` accordingly, which is prodived by `gnome-keyring-daemon -s`. For use in shells, I can easily do this in my `.zshrc`. However, I want `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` set at launch of my WM (i3) so that my launcher (rofi-menu) has access to it, but I cannot figure out where to do that.

I tried to do this in the X session startup, but that appears to be too early (I assume gnome-keyring-daemon is not running yet).

Where is the best place to manage this?

This is Ubuntu 20.04 with i3 and SDDM.